# Misunderstanding how to use constructor (no args)

Tags: java, syntax, constructor, compiler-errors

My instructions were to make a no-argument constructor with default values.

I am having difficulty setting up proper constructors to initialize my class variables `re` and `im`. I tried to create a default constructor and use it, but I have a number of errors indicating I am not doing it correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class Complex {
    // Constants (final)
    protected double re;   // the real part
    protected double imag;   // the imaginaryinary part
    // Variables
    public double product;

   public Complex() {}  

    // create a new object with the given real and imaginaryinary parts
    Complex() {
        this.re = real;
        imag = imaginary;
    }
....... Code goes on
```

I think most of my problems have to do with my constructor and lack of 'this'

Comment: What *exactly* are you asking? Please be specific.

Comment: If you want to use newlines in `printf`, use `%n` instead of `\n` because that will get the platform-dependent newline character. If you only use `\n`, your program will not work on OS X (Which uses `\r` instead of `\n`)

Comment: @AustinD I am asking how to fix my errors.

Comment: @Majora320 This is just something im messing around with to learn. I'm not trippin' over cross platform yet, because I have a lot to learn before I can learn what each OS needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 // create a new object with the given real and imaginaryinary parts
Complex() {
    this.re = 1.0;
    this.imag = 2.0;
}
```

Comment: This is the closest to my answer because I required NO ARGS and this was the only answer with NO ARGS

Answer (score 3):

Errors because you have missed the *args* to the *constructor*.

```
// create a new object with the given real and imaginaryinary parts
Complex(double real, double imaginary) {
    this.re = real;
    imag = imaginary;
}
```

If you need the values to be initialized properly you can use `final` modifyer to the args. See advice [Use final on constructor and setter parameters](https://blogs.oracle.com/tor/entry/code_advice_12_use_final).

```
Complex(final double real, final double imaginary) {
    this.re = real;
    imag = imaginary;
}
```

The object properties could be initialized early in the constructor or lately after the object is created, you need to use mutators to modify non-final properties of the object.

In early objects along with constructor you can initialize members *inline*.

A lot of other ways available to initialize the object in the last case, in most cases you should use a `public` modifyier on the method that mutate the state of the object by modifying its properties.

Comment: I want a no-argument constructor with default values. I'm sure I did it wrong.

Comment: you didn't use a default constructor, and how would you like initialize it via mutators or in the constructor?

Comment: in the constructor

Comment: I insist to use  a full constructor to initialize the values, unless the object is not managed. you can use constants like `static Complex DEFAULT = new Complex (1.0, 2.0);`

Comment: My assignment says I need to make a constructor with no arguments/parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You have a constructor in the `Complex` class, but it is not setup to accept arguments, yet you attempt to set class variables within the constructor as if you are. Change your constructor to:

```
// create a new object with the given real and imaginary parts
Complex(double real, double imaginary) {
    this.re = real;
    imag = imaginary;
}
```

Secondly, you are getting additional errors when calling:

```
Comp.Complex();
```

This is not valid line. You can call other methods on Comp (which should not be capitalized and should be called 'comp', like:

```
comp.reciprocal()
```

You can also have a no-args default constructor for defaults, which would look like:

```
public Complex(){
}
```

You don't need to initialize the doubles re and imaginary, as primitive doubles automatically initialize to 0.0.

If you want to initialize them to some other value, it would look like:

```
public Complex(){
    re = 100.00;  //or some other value
    imaginary = 200.00; //or some other value
}
```

Finally, you can have more than one constructor, as long as each has a different number of input arguments and/or different types. So it is acceptable to have both a default constructor and one that accepts the 2 doubles as inputs.

You really should read up on Java constructors. It's a very basic and core topic to any new Java developer and the issues you are having are easily correctable with just a little effort to learn the constructs of the language. There are many examples and tutorials on the web, here is just one of them: http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-constructor.html